# Problem with Variable Scoping in Rebol's Object

Tags: rebol

I have modified the rebodex app so that it can be called from rebol's console any time by typing rebodex. To show the title of the app, I need to store it in

```
app-title: system/script/header/title
```

so tha it could be used later in

```
view/new/title dex reform [self/app-title version]
```

That works but as you can see I have named the var name "app-title", but if I use "title" instead, the window caption would show weird stuff (vid code). Why ?

```
REBOL [
    Title: "Rebodex"
    Date: 23-May-2010
    Version: 2.1.1
    File: %rebodex.r
    Author: "Carl Sassenrath"
    Modification: "Rebtut"
    Purpose: "A simple but useful address book contact database."
    Email: %carl--rebol--com
    library: [
        level: 'intermediate
        platform: none
        type: 'tool
        domain: [file-handling DB GUI]
        tested-under: none
        support: none
        license: none
        see-also: none
    ]
]

rebodex.context: context [

    app-title: system/script/header/title
    version: system/script/header/version

    set 'rebodex func[][
    names-path: %names.r ;data file
    name-list: none
    fields: [name company title work cell home car fax web email smail notes updat]

    names: either exists? names-path [load names-path][
        [[name "Carl Sassenrath" title "Founder" company "REBOL Technologies"
        email "%carl--rebol--com" web "http://www.rebol.com"]]
    ]

    brws: [
        if not empty? web/text [
            if not find web/text "http://" [insert web/text "http://"]
            error? try [browse web/text]
        ]
    ]
    dial: [request [rejoin ["Dial number for " name/text "?  (Not implemented.)"] "Dial" "Cancel"]]

    dex-styles: stylize [
        lab: label  60x20 right bold middle font-size 11
        btn: button 64x20 font-size 11 edge [size: 1x1]
        fld: field  200x20 font-size 11 middle edge [size: 1x1]
        inf: info   font-size 11 middle edge [size: 1x1]
        ari: field wrap font-size 11 edge [size: 1x1] with [flags: [field tabbed]]
    ]

    dex-pane1: layout/offset [
        origin 0 space 2x0 across
        styles dex-styles
        lab "Name"    name: fld bold return
        lab "Title"   title: fld return
        lab "Company" company: fld return
        lab "Email"   email: fld return
        lab "Web"     brws web: fld return
        lab "Address" smail: ari 200x72 return
        lab "Updated" updat: inf 200x20 return
    ] 0x0
    updat/flags: none

    dex-pane2: layout/offset [
        origin 0 space 2x0 across
        styles dex-styles
        lab "Work #"  dial work: fld 140 return
        lab "Home #"  dial home: fld 140 return
        lab "Cell #"  dial cell: fld 140 return
        lab "Alt #"   dial car:  fld 140 return
        lab "Fax #"   fax: fld 140 return
        lab "Notes"   notes: ari 140x72 return
        pad 136x1 btn "Close" #"^q" [store-entry save-file unview]
    ] 0x0

    dex: layout [
        origin 8x8
        space 0x1
        styles dex-styles
        srch: fld 196x20 bold
        across
        rslt: list 180x150 [
            nt: txt 178x15 middle font-size 11 [
                store-entry curr: cnt find-name nt/text update-entry unfocus show dex
            ]
        ]
        supply [
            cnt: count + scroll-off
            face/text: ""
            face/color: snow
            if not n: pick name-list cnt [exit]
            face/text: select n 'name  face/font/color: black
            if curr = cnt [face/color: system/view/vid/vid-colors/field-select]
        ]
        sl: slider 16x150 [scroll-list] return

        return
        btn "New" #"^n" [new-name]
        btn "Del" #"^d" [delete-name unfocus update-entry search-all show dex]
        btn "Sort" [sort names sort name-list show rslt]
        return

        at srch/offset + (srch/size * 1x0)
        bx1: box dex-pane1/size
        bx2: box dex-pane2/size

        return
    ]

    bx1/pane: dex-pane1/pane
    bx2/pane: dex-pane2/pane
    rslt/data: []
    this-name: first names
    name-list: copy names
    curr: none
    search-text: ""
    scroll-off: 0

    srch/feel: make srch/feel [
        redraw: func [face act pos][
            face/color: pick face/colors face  system/view/focal-face
            if all [face = system/view/focal-face face/text  search-text] [
                search-text: copy face/text search-all
                if 1 = length? name-list [this-name: first name-list update-entry show dex]
            ]
        ]
    ]

    update-file: func [data] [
        set [path file] split-path names-path
        if not exists? path [make-dir/deep path]
        write names-path data
    ]

    save-file: has [buf] [
        buf: reform [{REBOL [Title: "Name Database" Date:} now "]^/[^/"]
        foreach n names [repend buf [mold n newline]]
        update-file append buf "]"
    ]

    delete-name: does [
        remove find/only names this-name
        if empty? names [append-empty]
        save-file
        new-name
    ]

    clean-names: function [][n][
        forall names [
            if any [empty? first names none? n: select first names 'name empty? n][
                remove names
            ]
        ]
        names: head names
    ]

    search-all: function [] [ent flds] [
        clean-names
        clear name-list
        flds: [name]
        either empty? search-text [insert name-list names][
            foreach nam names [
                foreach word flds [
                    if all [ent: select nam word  find ent search-text][
                        append/only name-list nam
                        break
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
        scroll-off: 0
        sl/data: 0
        resize-drag
        scroll-list
        curr: none
        show [rslt sl]
    ]

    new-name: does [
        store-entry
        clear-entry
        search-all
        append-empty
        focus name
    ;   update-entry
    ]

    append-empty: does [append/only names this-name: copy []]

    find-name: function [str][] [
        foreach nam names [
            if str = select nam 'name [
                this-name: nam
                break
            ]
        ]
    ]

    store-entry: has [val ent flag] [
        flag: 0
        if not empty? trim name/text [
            foreach word fields [
                val: trim get in get word 'text
                either ent: select this-name word [
                    if ent  val [insert clear ent val  flag: flag + 1]
                ][
                    if not empty? val [repend this-name [word copy val] flag: flag + 1]
                ]
                if flag = 1 [flag: 2  updat/text: form now]
            ]
            if not zero? flag [save-file]
        ]
    ]

    update-entry: does [
        foreach word fields [
            insert clear get in get word 'text any [select this-name word ""]
        ]
        show rslt
    ]

    clear-entry: does [
        clear-fields bx1
        clear-fields bx2
        updat/text: form now
        unfocus
        show dex
    ]

    show-names: does [
        clear rslt/data
        foreach n name-list [
            if n/name [append rslt/data n/name]
        ]
        show rslt
    ]

    scroll-list: does [
        scroll-off: max 0 to-integer 1 + (length? name-list) - (100 / 16) * sl/data
        show rslt
    ]

    do resize-drag: does [sl/redrag 100 / max 1 (16 * length? name-list)]

    center-face dex
    new-name
    focus srch
    show-names
    view/new/title dex reform [app-title version]
    insert-event-func [
        either all [event/type = 'close event/face = dex][
            store-entry
            unview
        ][event]
    ]
    do-events

    ]

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this

> title: fld return

so title is a rebol object ... not text.